# Status failed: While getting the whole doc in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In my scenario, I have to get the document from Word and send it to a server via a Word Add-In.

I added all the function which are given in the Office.js Documentation: [Get the whole document from an add-in for PowerPoint or Word](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word).

The `result.status` returned from the following code however is `Failed`. There no error shown in the console so I'm not able to see a reason why.

```js
sendDocument() {
    let self = this;
    window.Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed", {
        sliceSize: 100000
    }, function (result) {
        if (result.status === window.Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            let document = result.value;
            let documentState = {
                file: document,
                counter: 0,
                sliceCount: document.sliceCount
            };
            self.updateStatus("Getting document ", document.size + " bytes");
            self.getSlice(documentState);
        } else {
            self.updateStatus(result.status);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You mentioned Word Online, is this only happening in Online (i.e. it works on the Desktop)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply@Marc LaFleur, I solved the issue. Actually the issue was in my react js code.